# airflow shows timezone as UTC

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have set timezone to "**Canada/Central**" however dag info page shows it as **UTC** only.

**Code**

```py
support_email = Variable.get("prod_support_email")
args = {
    'owner': 'Gaurang Shah',
    'email': [support_email],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 0,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 9, 17,  tzinfo=local_tz),
}
```

**Info Page**

[image]

Comment: Have you try to change default_timezone parameter on airflow.cfg? This parameter has default value for  UTC timezone that`s why your dag is getting UTC tz. Also on the new release of airflow(Airflow 1.10.10) this type o change can be done by WebServer User Interface -

Comment: I haven't change the default timezone. However, I got from the airflow dag that I can configure different timezone for different dag. and was trying that options. However it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to answer the question is clarify the question.

1. how to know the dag is a Time zone aware DAGs.
   following the office doc [enter link description here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/timezone.html), you can set up a timezone awared dags and check it by print dags timezone.
   It is programmatic way, you can also check it in dags tree view as follow picutres.
   there will be localtimezone, dag timezone, if you dags is right, you will get 3 timezone(utc, local and dag)
   [image]
2. if the task info page showed utc means the dags is a utc timezone dage?
   My answer is No.  No matter how you dags change, the default timezone will be UTC in info page. It is not the dags timezoneinfo.